# Using subprocess with openssl in a python script

Tags: python, openssl, subprocess

I have thoroughly confused myself with Python subprocess syntax!

I would like to decrypt a string using openssl from within a Python script.

Here is the bash script snippet that works:

```
readable_code=$(echo "$encrypted_code"| openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:$key)
```

So in a python script - I understand that to run this same bash command I should use subprocess.
I need to Pipe the echo to the openssl command and as well pass in the encrypted_code and key variables dynamically(its in a loop).

Anyone out there know the correct syntax for this ?
Below's snippet should give the background to what i'm trying to do.
thank-you

```
import subprocess 

    key = "my-secret-key"
    file = list_of_ips #format ip:long-encrypted-code

with open(file_read) as f:
    #read in all connecion requests
    content=f.readlines()
    #create  list that will hold all ips whose decrypted codes have passed test
    elements = []
    for ip_code in content:
        #grab the ip address before the colon
        ip = ip_code.split(':', 1)[0]
        #grab the encrypted code after the colon
        code = ip_code.split(':',1)[1]

        #here is where I want to run the bash command and assign to a python variable
        decrypted_code = subprocess....using code and key variables
        ...on it goes....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you to use [Plumbum](https://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) Python library to write shell scripts.
Particularly it has a [convenient way to do piping](https://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/local_commands.html#pipelining) and [redirection](https://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/local_commands.html#input-output-redirection).

I don't really understood what exact task you trying to solve, but your code could look approximately like this:

```
from plubum.cmd import openssl

with open('file') as f:
    for ip_code in f:
        (openssl['whatever', 'params'] << ip_code)()
```

Comment: Hi Gill - it works ! thanks for the rapid response.            Heres my code:   decrypted_code = (openssl['enc', '-aes-128-cbc', '-a', '-d', '-salt', '-pass', 'pass:' + key] << ip_code)()

Answer (score 3):

To emulate the shell command:

```
$ readable_code=$(echo "$encrypted_code"| openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass "pass:$key")
```

using `subprocess` module in Python:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = 'openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass'.split()
p = Popen(cmd + ['pass:' + key], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
readable_code = p.communicate(encrypted_code)[0]
```